# graph schema design: users->post->comments

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j, schema

I just started using neo4j and I have some doubt on how should I model a users->post->comments schema....actually I did something like this:

```
type User {
  uuid: ID!
  username: String
  posts: [Post] @relation(name: "HAS_POSTS", direction: "OUT")
  comments: [Comment] @relation(name: "POST_COMMENTS", direction: "OUT")
}

type Post {
  uuid: ID!
  text: String
  owner: User @relation(name: "HAS_POSTS", direction: "IN")
  comments: [Comment] @relation(name: "HAS_COMMENTS", direction: "OUT")
}

type Comment {
  uuid: ID!
  text: String
  owner: User @relation(name: "POST_COMMENTS", direction: "IN")
}
```

saving the the uuid of the referenced object, for example each post has the the owner uuid as property and it has the relation too (the same for the comments) but I'm not 100% that this is correct. Reading this article:
https://neo4j.com/developer/modeling-designs/

I understand why use the relation is better then the property, but if I want to edit the post and be sure that only the owner of the post has the permission of doing that I was thinking to search the post by the uuid of the post and the uuid of the user and then set the data on that particular node...something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Post) WHERE p.uuid = post.uuid AND p.owner = $cypherParams.user.uuid
      SET p += post
      RETURN p
```

is this pattern good? or saving the owner property is useless and can brake the consistency of my data?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there're many definitive answers when it comes to data modelling in any database, graphs included. What we *can* do is see how that specific 'edit a post' query might if you *were* to use relationships, so you can see the comparison.

First, let's fake up your `cypherParams` variable for our testing:

```
:param cypherParams => {
  user: {
    uuid: 123
  },
  post: {
    text: 'Made the post better',
    uuid: 2
  }
}
```

Let's model a simplified version of the problem with just Post and User nodes for now:

```
MERGE (u1: User { uuid: 123, name: 'Pablissimo' })
MERGE (u2: User { uuid: 234, name: 'Francesco' })
MERGE (p1: Post { uuid: 1, text: 'This post is great' })
MERGE (p2: Post { uuid: 2, text: 'This post not so great' })
MERGE (p3: Post { uuid: 3, text: 'This post is pretty good' })
MERGE (u1)-[:HAS_POST]->(p1)
MERGE (u1)-[:HAS_POST]->(p2)
MERGE (u2)-[:HAS_POST]->(p3)
RETURN p1, p2, p3, u1, u2
```

[image]

Given that, if I were user 123 trying to update post 2, how would that query look?

```
MATCH (u: User { uuid: $cypherParams.user.uuid })-[:HAS_POST]->(p: Post { uuid: $cypherParams.post.uuid })
SET p += $cypherParams.post
RETURN p
```

[image]

It's not really more complicated than the query where Post nodes have an `owner` property, but it has all the advantages of having a clear data model that leans on the strengths of the graph database.

Storing redundant data feels like a premature optimisation - until you find you need it to get you out of a jam, I would suggest that your original model looks like a good fit for a graph. If that isn't enough to give you confidence then experiment, trying both approaches and seeing how the queries would look and how the model *feels* to use for your use cases. And remember - you can always refactor your graph towards relationships or towards storing extra properties and back again as your requirements change.